# WebSocket options for use with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: websocket, arduino

My understanding is that there are 2 main option for implementing websockets on a Pi
1 - Tornado - a light Python based web framework
2 - NodeJS+SocketIO

Pros-cons of each?

Is anyone familiar with either or perhaps can suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js and socket.io is better option because Socket.IO support mobile device and realtime connectivity on every browse.

More details see this link http://socket.io/#browser-support

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently playing around with Tornado - here's where I am up to:

[Raspberry Pi and Tornado Websockets Part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYkxpwRcHI8)

I've also created the html client but not yet recorded part 2. Feel free to take a look. Part 2 should be there today and I'll be continuing to develop/evolve the code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a third alternative is too use [Java WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) (though the use of Java on a Pi can be discussed...)